# Stream Stop/Close doesn't opened by navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc, opentok

I use the following code to initialise camera for my web-application:

```
navigator
  .mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(gotStream)
  .catch(handleError);

function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("Got a new stream.")
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
}
```

I'm able to render my camera feed, it works fine.

And while stopping my stream I do this:

```
 window
  .stream
  .getTracks()
  .forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
  });
```

But for some reason the camera stays on, but if I open up inspect element it stops. Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried running your code snippet on Chrome, but it is working as expected, the camera is getting closed properly. Are you seeing any error when you run your code?

Comment: I dont see any error, try doing it multiple times without refresing.

Comment: Trying adding some counter on the number of GUM requests and the stop call to see if you are closing all the requests properly. I don't see any issue with the code.